# Microsoft Office web viewer for Azure Storage hosted documents

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, sharepoint, ms-wopi

My application is hosted in a VM on Microsoft Azure and handles MS-Office documents (.doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx). Users need to view these documents stored on Azure Storage Service.

I'm looking for a viewer to integrate with my application. Before showing these files, my application does some validations, to check if user can view the file, print or download. In some cases, when users request to view an OpenXML document (.docx), my application first modify the file before showing it to user.

My 1st choice was using the free viewer from Microsoft ( http://products.office.com/en-us/office-online/view-office-documents-online ), integrating it to my application through an iframe, but I cannot limit user access on the files - there's no parameters to disable printing or download.

My 2nd choice was converting these documents to PDF and using a PDF viewer, but convert these documents to PDF requires proprietary solutions (like [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/)) and Excel files don't have a good appearance when converted to PDF.

After eliminating the options above, I was thinking on a new VM with Office Web Parts and Sharepoint to do this. Is Office Web Apps a good alternative? Can I use Office 365 instead? Can I integrate with my application, limit user actions on the documents and view files out of OneDrive or Sharepoint database?

Please, let me know if you have any other solutions.
Thank you.

Comment: did the below solution work for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install Office Web Apps Server on a VM in Azure, you don't need SharePoint or anything else, Office Web Apps Server is a standalone product and it's free for Viewing only. Web Apps Server has well documented WOPI (Web Application Open Platform Interface Protocol) which you can use to connect to your custom document system. There are various blogs and samples around on how to do a custom host for WOPI. Here are some Resources.

[Introduction to WOPI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officedevdocs/archive/2013/03/20/introducing-wopi.aspx)

[WOPI Protocol Documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh622722(v=office.12).aspx)

[Example of Custom WOPI Host Build with MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2013/07/22/building-an-office-web-apps-owa-wopi-host.aspx)

[WOPI -- Good Simple Explanation](http://msalmanshakeel.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/introducing-wopi.html)

Have a look at [CheckFileInfo Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh745881(v=office.12).aspx), it has an option to pass true to "DisablePrint" and loads of other options, there are some undocumented one like FileSharingUrl which I found when tinkering with SharePoint 2013 & Office Web App.

Note that Office Web App Server will not install on a VM with SQL Server or any other server product like SharePoint. I am not sure if you can use the Office Web Server on Office.com to connect to your own Document System via WOPI Protocol

Comment: Thank you pateketu! It helped me a lot. I've installed OWA and it's working integrated to my application through an iframe. I didn't know about building my own WOPI server. Do you know if the config options "DisablePrint" and "FileSharingUrl" are working with the Office Web Apps 2013 SP1? Can I disable print or download when users viewing documents?

Comment: Glad to help!, I think DisablePrint etc should work with OWA 2013 SP1 also. There is also a DownloadUrl property in CheckFileJson, so I guess if you don't pass a value for it then download button will also be disabled. However too make use of this you properties you must provide your own WOPI Host which could be just an ASP.NET Handler or a simple WebAPI controller with two Actions  CheckFileInfo and GetFile.

Comment: @pateketu I guess there are some changes to the way Microsoft provided MWA Server, I am to build a solution for a client, whose business is cloud storage, what path would suggest I follow if I have to build a POC before acquiring the Cloud Storage Partners Program, I mean any trial? Also I would like you to know that my client is more interested in Microsoft Hosted MS Office Apps, without Sharepoint.

Comment: @MuhammadMamoorKhan not sure I get your question, What type of PoC are you building?

Comment: I need to build an editor/viewer for office documents stored on a cloud storage.

Comment: There are loads of them available, why do you want to build your own? building a viewer is simpler, not the editor

Answer (score 0):

Per the EULA Office Web Apps / Office Online Server may not be deployed in Azure (or any other public cloud for the matter). Per the EULA when you install OOS:
User Rights…
You may run any number of instances of the server software in any number of physical and virtual operating system environments on any Server dedicated to Customer's use.  Server is defined as a physical hardware system capable of running server software.

Basically because the physical Servers in Azure are shared by multiple customers, by definition they are not dedicated to a single customer's use. Hence why you won't find any reference on a Microsoft web site depicting any scenarios where OWA or OOS is deployed in Azure.